# filling one table column with if else statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to check if a product is one of TOP 10 product (from eye side of selling in Sales.SalesOrderDetails) make one column and set it to YES or NO

I have TOP 10 products of MAX selling like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 p.Name , COUNT(*) 'Num of sell' FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD 
inner join Production.Product p on SOD.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
```

now i want another table which is all of products and I want to somehow put a column with a if/else statement and put yes or no in there. like:

```
SELECT p.Name, @someVariable FROM Production.Product p
IF p.Name IN 
(SELECT TOP 10 p.Name , COUNT(*) 'Num of sell' FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail SOD 
inner join Production.Product p on SOD.ProductID = p.ProductID
GROUP BY p.Name
ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC)
@someVariable = 'YES'
ELSE @someVariable = 'NO'
```

any idea ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do:

```
SELECT p.Name,
    CASE WHEN X.ProductID IS NULL THEN 'NO' ELSE 'YES' END AS InTopTen
FROM Production.Product p
LEFT JOIN
(
     SELECT TOP 10 ProductID FROM Sales.SalesOrderDetail
     GROUP BY ProductID 
     ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
) X
ON X.ProductID = p.ProductID
```

Comment: @Syzmon thank you, it helps :)
also if I want to add its unitprice which is in sales orderdetail, how can i do that ?

Comment: Join the whole query as it is now again to sales order details